# Environment variable not properly defined in Django

Tags: django

I am trying to run the django `runserver` command, but I'm getting the following error:

> You must define the  environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before calling it

This is my manage.py file

```
  import os
  import sys
  if __name__ == "__main__":
      os.environ.setdefault(
          "DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE",
          "it.settings"
      )

    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line

    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
```

Comment: please post your manage.py file, it should have something like `os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", <settings_file>)`

Comment: @RajatSingh put that in the question, with proper formatting

Comment: @awwester i had posted the code of mine manage.py file